# How to monitor for new tags entering the system?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been watching a user pick a bunch of low hanging fruit by adding text to new wiki tags. There's nothing wrong with that. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5530220.

This happens frequently, and I don't believe its coincidence that a particular user stumbles across 6 or 8 new tags while trolling questions over the course of a day.

How does a person know a new wiki tag entered the system? Is there a little script somewhere that can poll for this sort of thing?

Comment: No script needed, just visit http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new every day :)

Comment: I think he needs to slow down a bit. Here's the latest for [tag:xcode-tools]: *"iOS development tools like Email Newsletter, Sponsorship that you can use in Cocoa to develop a rich iOS application"*. Worse, someone has already approved it.

Comment: Agreed, most of the suggested tag wikis are bad and should be rejected. Eventually the automated script should kick in and an edit ban will be placed on the user.

Comment: If you request plan a burination request for this tag, here are some more of the same family: [tag:phone] [tag:call] [tag:phonecalls] [tag:cellphone]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does a person know a new wiki tag entered the system?

By visiting the [recently created tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) page.

Answer (score 5):

> There's nothing wrong with that. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5530220.

Yes, there is *definitely* something wrong with that. There are, in fact, two problems with that:

1. Someone suggested this tag wiki edit.
2. Three experienced users, in which we the community place our trust, voted to approve this edit.

There is nothing useful about that tag. It needs to be *obliterated*, not have a wiki created for it. Because I like numbered lists, here's a few things that are wrong with that tag:

1. It has only been applied to 1 question and has not proven its usefulness as a means of categorizing questions.
2. Its usefulness as a means for categorizing questions is not self-evident.
3. It is neither a word, nor does it refer to a well-known product, code identifier, or concept. The only question to which it has been applied is asking something about HTML5, but as far as I can tell, there is no "telpad" in the HTML5 specification.
4. That is a terrible wiki excerpt. It doesn't even *hint* at what this might have to do with computer programming. Perhaps because it has nothing to do with computer programming.

Anyway, to justify posting this answer, I'll repost Aziz's comment as an answer: You can easily monitor for new tags by checking the [New tab on the Tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new]). This is a great way to check both for bad new tags (because it is much easier to clean them up when they are used only infrequently) and for egregious behavior like this.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I placed the example for those who wanted to know the person doing it. I did not comment on the quality of the tag because I know nothing about 'telpad'. I skipped it during review.

Comment: Fair enough. I would have posted a comment, but there are no bulleted lists in comments. :-c

Comment: Regarding your first point: I think there is a script that removed this tag if this tag will not be used by at least another question in some time. The question would be, if the tag is removed, will the user also lose the gained reputation from the edit the same way this is done on other posts?

Comment: The script [removes the tag after 6 months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/245167) if no other question uses it @ArtjomB.